# Selenium Python is it possible select input field by label name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a complicated div section like below , I am trying to insert name after check label name.
Is it possible in python selenium ?

```
<div class="section_1">
    <label>
        <div>Name</div>
    </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="b4bf265013b0ac0">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying something like that, but not getting any solution.

```
label = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form//label')
if lable == 'Name'
    then select this lable field
```

Comment: If the text within the div tag is "Name", then you want to select the label. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @Sushil By label name I want to sendkey to input field , this input field is for name.

Comment: Okay...So you want to send the name within the label to the input field. Am I right?

Comment: @Sushil Yes you are right !

Comment: Okay...Check out my solution. I am still not very clear with your requirement, so if I have done anything wrong or you want anything to be added, pls let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any the of following `xpath` to achieve this.

Xpath 1:

```
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[./div[text()='Name']]/following-sibling::div[1]/input")
```

Xpath 2:

```
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'Name')]/following-sibling::div[1]/input")
```

Xpath 3:

```
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(.,'Name')]/following::input[1]")
```

Xpath 4:

```
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[./div[text()='Name']]/following::input[1]")
```

You can parameterized the field as well.

```
lableName="Name"
input=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[./div[text()='{}']]/following-sibling::div[1]/input".format(lableName))
```

Comment: Awesome answer !

Answer (score 0):

To select an element by the text it contains, you can simply use `find_element_by_link_text` like this:

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('section_1')

label_div_text = div.find_element_by_link_text("NAME").text
```

If you want to send this text to the input field, then you can add these lines yo your code:

```
input_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cc-m-form-view-input-wrapper').find_element_by_xpath('.//input')

input_field.send_keys(label_div_text)
```

Comment: My prime issue is I want to select input field by label name, example if label name is "NAME", select input witch is after label name "NAME".  I have edited my question and remove class. I am able to select an input field by class or xpath !